# Skip brackets when reading text file into NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a textfile that looks like so:

```
[142, 5068, 3648, 6454, 5895, 4669, ..., 1626, 5665]
[280, 1076, 3509, 2713, 2176, 3764, ..., 4655, 3120]
[280, 6322, 5545, 101, 3218, 5308, ..., 3431, 4535]
[142, 5415, 164, 8507, 985, 8545, 2619, ..., 5757, 1538]
[71, 554, 4525, 94, 940, 4794, 1631, 1310, ..., 5474, 8179]
[71, 5639, 8195, 5706, 8300, 8206, 3268]
[142, 5068, 3648, 6454, 5895, 4669, 1071, ..., 4703, 6007, 2139, 6967, 3507, 7573, 1848, 1626, 5665]
[280, 1076, 3509, 2713, 2176, 3764, 2265, ..., 4655, 3120]
```

I want to read them into NumPy as an array of arrays that will look like so:

```
routes = [
[142, 5068, 3648, 6454, 5895, 4669, ..., 1626, 5665],
[280, 1076, 3509, 2713, 2176, 3764, ..., 4655, 3120],
[280, 6322, 5545, 101, 3218, 5308, ..., 3431, 4535],
[142, 5415, 164, 8507, 985, 8545, 2619, ..., 5757, 1538],
[71, 554, 4525, 94, 940, 4794, 1631, 1310, ..., 5474, 8179],
[71, 5639, 8195, 5706, 8300, 8206, 3268],
[142, 5068, 3648, 6454, 5895, 4669, 1071, ..., 4703, 6007, 2139, 6967, 3507, 7573, 1848, 1626, 5665],
[280, 1076, 3509, 2713, 2176, 3764, 2265, ..., 4655, 3120]
]
```

What is the most pythonic way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried until now?

Comment: I have tried using: route= np.loadtxt(open("route.txt", "rb"), dtype=int, delimiter=",", skiprows=0) but I am unable how to exclude the square brackets when reading it in

Comment: You can open it as a plain text file, read the lines as strings, for every line remove the brackets, split it by commas and convert it to integers.

Comment: Are the '...' in the file, or just your summary?  Do the lines differ in length?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
routes = np.loadtxt('route.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=int,
                     converters={0: lambda s: s[1:], -1: lambda s: s[:-1]})
```

Answer (score 1):

The file appears to be a python data structure, so you can convert each line using the `ast` module:

```
import ast
import numpy as np

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
   a = np.array([ast.literal_eval(line) for line in f])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest options would just be to convert each line individually. Strip will get rid of the characters at the beginning and end of each line.

```
text_file = open("route.txt", "r")

# List of strings for each line
lines = text_file.readlines()
route = None
for i in range(len(lines)):
    # Gets rid of brackets and newline and converts to numpy array
    arr = np.fromstring(lines[0].strip('[]\n'), dtype=int, sep=',')
    # This just instantiates the array with the correct shape as soon as its known
    if i == 0:
        route = np.zeros((len(lines), len(arr)))
    route[i] = arr
    
print(route)
```